# change the publishing author when synchronising from overleaf to git repo

Tags: git, github

A friend (**F**) created an overleaf project and added me (**M**). In that project **M** (ie **M**=me) created a github repo out of this project. Now, every time I or that friend publish a change to the github repo in Overleaf, it's always registered in GitHub as a commit from one and the same User (*viz.* my GitHub user **G**).

1. Ideally I want that, whenever my friend (GitHub user  = **H**) publishes changes in overleaf, that in GitHub the commits register **H** as author.
2. If this is not possible, is there a way to change something either in GitHub or Overleaf (or via git commands), so that changes published in overleaf are registered just under user **H** instead of just under user **G** (= creator of the Repo)?

*I. e.* right now all commits are {**G**}. Ideally I want commits to be registered as both {**G**,**H**} depending upon which overleaf editor publishes the change, but would be happy if all are published under {**H**}.

Answer (score 1):

Since M linked Overleaf to the GitHub repository (and would have given Overleaf push permissions in the process), this is probably not possible unless the repository can somehow be re-linked by H, which does not [seem to be possible currently](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/492878/change-github-repository-on-overleaf).

A workaround would be to copy the Overleaf project to a new project (which would delete history, as per the linked answer), and then ask H to link it to a new GitHub repository.